# Acquia Dev Desktop and Drupal give sometimes 500 Internal Error

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-500

I decided to try Drupal. 
So, I installed **Acquia Dev Desktop 2**.

Then, I downloaded **Drupal (8.0.2)** and imported it (+).

Then, I opened the Drush console and installed the site with drush **site-install**.

*And it worked*. But, *constantly*, I received the following ERROR…

```
500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

**Well, it´s not constantly**, sometimes, I can manage the site.

**The strange thing is that when the 500 page appears, if I reload it a couple of times, I see the admin or page.**

In consequence, *I want to resolve that to not stay clicking and clicking until I can manage the site.*

**Anyone knows WHY…?**

I am using  Acquia Dev Desktop 2

OS: Windows 10

Local site: http://site.dd:8083

Local code: C:\Drupal\Sites\devdesktop\site

Acquia: C:\Drupalservices

Local database: site

PHP version: 5.6.14

Comment: Maybe this could be a solution for you: https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/167#issuecomment-96054431

Comment: I'm experience the same. Did you found a solution?